# Can't find a theory which meets conditions

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm trying to solve this problem.

There is a language $L = \{f\}$ with equality (we can use '$=$'), where $f$ is a unary function.

Our goal is to decide and prove, whether there is a theory $T$, such that for any realisation $\mathbf{M}$ of language $\mathcal{L}$ stands:

$$
\begin{array}{lrcl}
\mbox{(a)} & M \models T &\iff& \mbox{range of f is finite} \\
\mbox{(b)} & M \models T &\iff& \mbox{range of f is infinite}
\end{array}
$$
I think that I've solved the first question a) finite but I'm not sure:

a) yes, there exists such theory
   Prove: $ T = \{ \exists y \forall x(f(x)=y) \}$

This theory consists of 1 formula which forces that the range of $f$ is finite.

b) I don't have an idea. The only thing I can say is that $U$ (universe) should be infinite because otherwise, the range of $f(x)$ would be finite.

I suppose that there is no chance to find a theory which satisfies b) but I'm not sure and I can't prove it.

Comment: mathjax is the preferred way to write mathematical formulas on this sight. I've edited your post to use it. I have also changed "output" to "range" which is what I think you mean and is more standard in mathematical parlance.

Comment: Your a) is fine: in any model of your $T$, the range of $f$ will be finite (one element). Just FYI, If you also wanted to constrain all models of $T$ to be finite, then simply add to $T$ a sentence expressing that $f$ is a surjection. All models of the resulting theory will have only one element.

Comment: For (a), the problem is asking for a formula that is satisfied by *every* function with a finite range, not just by *some* functions with finite ranges. The problem says that for *every* realization, something should happen.

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, you're right.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that (a) and (b) are separate bi-implications.

Comment: To clarify one final point, is the theory $T$ allowed to be infinite?

Comment: @CarlMummert Yes, it could be any theory.  So from your previous comment, it seems that my solution is wrong.

Comment: @CarlMummert On the other hand. If I have a theory $ T = \{ \exists y \forall x(f(x)= y) \}$. This theory forces realisation that $f(x) = constant$, so it is True. For every realisation $f$, range is finite $<=>$ M I= T.

Comment: @Milano: Here is a counterexample to that. Suppose we have a function $f$ on a two-element set $\{a,b\}$ with $f(a) = a$ and $f(b) = b$. Then the range of that $f$ is finite, but your formula is not satisfied, because $f$ is not constant. You are looking for a formula that holds for *every* function with finite range; unfortunately, as my answer shows, there is no solution for part (a).

Comment: @CarlMummert For every realization holds the<=>. And the expression realization forces that each function we consider should satisfies the formula. Your conterexample is not a part of any realization because your function does not belongs to any realization of the theory. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Every function $f$ gives rise to a realization $M_f$, including the one that I wrote. The question (a) asks for you to find a $T$ such that, for *every* function $f$, $M_f \vDash T$ if and only if $f$ has a finite range.  What you are doing is only half of that: you have a $T$ such that *if* $M_f$ satisfies $T$ then $f$ has a finite range. That is a much easier problem. . But that is not what the question seems to be asking. It does not say "any realization of $T$", it says "any realization of the language $\mathcal{L}$".

Answer (score 1):

Originally, from your attempts, it seemed that you were looking for a theory that only has (a') finite or (b') infinite models, for which your answer to (a') works and one can answer (b') by noting that a function $f$ from $U$ to $U$ that is one-to-one (injective) and not onto (not surjective) cannot have a finite range.

Now, it seems you want (a) a $T$ that characterises the models where $f$ has a finite range and (b) a $T$ that characterises the models where $f$ has an infinite range. The answer to (a) is that no such $T$ exists, which can be proved using something called the compactness theorem that I suspect you haven't studied yet. For (b) such a $T$ does exist: for $n = 2, 3, \ldots$, let $\phi_n(x_1, \ldots x_n)$ be a frmula with free variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ that asserts that the $x_i$ are pairwise distinct. (I leave it to you to design $\phi_n$.) Then take $T$ to comprise the infinite lists of sentences:
$$
\exists x_1 \exists x_2\,\phi_2(f(x_1), f(x_2)) \\
\exists x_1 \exists x_2\exists x_3\,\phi_3(f(x_1), f(x_2), f(x_3)) \\
\vdots \\
\exists x_1 \ldots \exists x_n\, \phi_n(f(x_1), \ldots, f(x_n))\\
\vdots
$$

Comment: I've said that here: "The only thing I can say is that U (universe) should be infinite because otherwise, the output of f(x) would be finite." I think that If the U was let's say {1,2,3}, the range would be finite, wouldn't be?

Comment: So express the property that $f$ is one-to-one and not onto as a sentence in the language $\cal L$ and take $T$ to consist of that sentence, then ...

Comment: @Milano Is there any function from $\{1,2,3\}$ to itself that is injective but not surjective?

Comment: $ T = \{  \forall x(f(x)=x) \}$  would force $f(x)$ to be One To One but it is not enough because I have to make sure that universe is infinite.

Comment: @Milano The identity function is surjective.

Comment: @BrianO My latest comment was answer to Rob Arthans comment. The injective $f$ would be for example $ T = \{ \forall x(f(x)=x*x) \}$, which would be probably enough but we do not have multiplication in our language so we probably can't use it in our Theory.

Comment: What does $\forall x\forall y(f(x) = f(y) \rightarrow x = y)$ say about $f$? Now see what you can say with a sentence that begins $\exists x\forall y\lnot$?

Comment: @Milano Never mind that: there's no other function symbol available, and even if there were, without sentences in $T$ characterizing "multiplication" the symbol for that binary operation could have any interpretation, including constant functions. // But this is beside the point. See Rob Arthan's last comment.

Comment: @RobArthan The first formula says that the function is not surjective. The second formula says that  the function could be surjective.

Comment: @Milano If by "the first formula" you mean $\forall x \forall y(f(x)=f(y)\to x=y)$ then no it does not say that "$f$ is not surjective" (onto). If by "the second formula" you mean $\exists x\forall y\neg?$, ... well, that's not even a formula yet, it's waiting for you to supply something for "?".

Comment: The question asks for a formula such that, for every model $M$, the range of $f^M$ is infinite if and only if $M$ satisfies the formula. So it will not work to say that $f$ is not surjective, because there are some surjective functions with infinite ranges.

Comment: @CarlMummert: $T$ can be infinite, so the answer to (b) is yes.

Comment: My answer now answers both the question the OP was apparently trying to solve and the one actually posed.

Answer (score 0):

Part (b) is possible. Let $T_I$ include, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the formula
$$
(\exists x_1)\cdots(\exists x_n)[f(x_1) \not = f(x_2) \land \cdots \land f(x_1) \not = f(x_n) \land f(x_2) \not = f(x_3)\land \cdots ]$$

where every possible nonequality between variables $x_i $ and $x_j$ for $i,j \leq n$ is included. Then any model of $T_I$ will have a function with infinite range, because the range has at least $n$ elements for every $n \in\mathbb{N}$, and conversely if $f$ is any function then the model $M_f$ obtained from $f$ will satisfy $T_I$.

Part (a) is impossible, by compactness. Suppose that $T$ was a theory such that $M_f$ satisfies $T$ if and only if $f$ has finite range. Then every finite subset of $T \cup T_I$ is satisfiable, because we can find functions with arbitrarily large finite ranges. Thus $T \cup T_I$ is satisfiable by some model $M$. Then the function $f$ in $M$ will have infinite range (because $M$ satisfies $T_I$), but $M$ will also satisfy $T$, which is a contradiction.